# Are mappings subdirectories supported in wiremock?

Tags: java, json, mocking, yaml, wiremock

I am trying to put mappings json files in a subdirectories due to different requirements based on diff profiles.

I have it working with default /mappings directory and all mappings work ok in postman.

```
WiremockConfiguration options = options()
.usingFilesUnderDirectory(System.getPtoperty(“user.dir”) + “/app/src/main/resources”
```

src/main/resources

-mappings

—folderA

—folderB

—folderC

But once I try to place json files under sub directory of “mappings” folder, no mappings get picked up and /__admin/mappings endpoint show a total of 0.

```
WiremockConfiguration options = options()
.usingFilesUnderDirectory(System.getPtoperty(“user.dir”) + “/app/src/main/resources**/mappings/aws**”
```

(Note the path difference)

I am just wondering if mappings folder subdirectories are even supported in wire mock or have I configured something incorrectly? It seems something too simple to be not supported by wiremock!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it but for anyone facing similar problem u need to make “mappings” subdirectory of your custom folders.

src/main/resources

-my_wiremock_mappings

—folderA

—— mappings (should contain json files)

—folderB

—— mappings

—folderC

—— mappings

```
WiremockConfiguration options = options()
.usingFilesUnderDirectory(System.getPtoperty(“user.dir”) + “/app/src/main/resources/my_wiremock_mappings/folderA”
```

There is no need to add “mappings” to the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a classpath ant pattern, you have to add *.json at the end.

`@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 8081, stubs = "classpath:/stubs/**/*.json")`

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/main/spring-cloud-contract-wiremock/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/contract/wiremock/WireMockConfiguration.java#L213